# For readdir_r, may entry and result have the same value?

Tags: c, readdir

Can I use `readdir_r` like this? I don't find anything about it in the spec, but maybe I'm just blind...

```
readdir_r(dir, entry, &entry);
```

Comment: `man readdir_r` in your system.

Comment: `readdir_t()` sets its `result` argument to `NULL` when the end of the directory is reached. Keep this in mind if you allocate `entry` with `malloc()` (possible memory leak). Otherwise you can do what you do since both `entry` and `&entry` are passed by value to the function.

Comment: @MYMNeo: There's no seperate manpage about it on my system, and there's nothing about my question in the `readdir` manpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's readdir_**r**, and the second argument is a *pointer* to a struct dirent, not a struct dirent itself, and the third argument is a pointer to pointer to a struct dirent, which receives the address of the struct dirent or NULL for end-of-directory. The usage is something like

```
struct dirent* pentry = malloc(offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) +
                             pathconf(dirpath, _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1);
if (!pentry)
    out_of_memory();

for (;;){
   struct dirent* result;
   readdir_r(dirp, pentry, &result); // you can check the return code, but it only fails if dirp is invalid
   if( !result )
       break;
   // process result
}
free(pentry);
```

As Hristo points out above, the arguments are passed by value so you *could* pass the address of the second arg (pentry) as the third arg (i.e., &pentry) -- it doesn't affect readir_r, which has no way to tell. But that will store NULL in pentry when you reach the end of the directory, but you need the value of pentry in order to free the malloced buffer it  points to. So forget about whether using the address of the second argument is allowed ... doing so is pointless, misleading, and results in a memory leak.

For the spec of readdir_r, see
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/readdir.3.html
or
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html

Comment: so can I not use `readdir_r()` without using a `malloc()` for dirent? or can I just pass a pointer pointing my `dirent struct` on the stack?

Comment: @Jawsmerc Yes, you can allocate a `struct dirent` on the stack. The d_name member will have enough room for a path of length NAME_MAX.